# How to get the product sku from order items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-rest-api

For Api on page "woocommerce_thankyou" need get sku.
I have:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):
   $product = new WC_Product($item_id);
   $item_sku[] = $product->get_sku();
endforeach;
```

But not works.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? What is the behaviour/error message you see instead?

Comment: There are no errors, but for some reason this variable is not displayed on the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're fiddling around on the actual template page ;-)
In Wordpress we mainly use [action hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to accomplish tasks like this.

Try this, place it in the (child) theme `functions.php`.

NOTE: only for WooCommerce 3+

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'order_created_get_skus', 10 );

function order_created_get_skus($order_id){

  $item_sku = array();
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

  foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product = wc_get_product($item->get_product_id());
    $item_sku[] = $product->get_sku();
  }

  // now do something with the sku array 

}
```

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the line `new WC_Product($item_id)` is obsolete. [link](https://github.com/afterpay/afterpay-woocommerce/issues/9). And I'm trying to check this variable out for a page in this way - `print_r( $item_sku );`

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry, my code was not correct. I've updated my answer with correct functions for WOO 3+

Comment: I checked the code is working. Thank you so much!

Comment: One note to add, this will fail if the product in question was deleted after the order was created, because $product will return false and get_sku throws a fatal errror. A slightly easier way to do this: $item->get_product()->get_sku();